# My site is trying to use another site's let's-encrypt SSL Cert on the same server

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, certbot

I set up a website on my Digital Ocean Debian machine, like I've done a dozen times before. This time when I visit http://example.com, it redirects to https (I don't know how or why), and I get a "Your connection is not secure" browser error, when I view the details it says:

> example.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>   `another.example.net`, `www.another.example.net`
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I haven't set up a SSL cert for example.com yet, but it's trying to use an other SSL cert.

Here's the `sites-enabled/example.com.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin alan@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is it trying to use that other cert?

Comment: I wonder if the browser is using opportunistic https to select https instead of http? Since https isn't configured for that domain it's defaulting to the default https server. I'm not an Apache expert, but that would make sense for Nginx.

Comment: You're accessing HTTP and get a certificate error? That doesn't make sense. Are you sure you're not accessing via HTTPS (or it might be redirecting to HTTPS)?

Comment: It redirects to https, but I don't know how or why. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: It redirects to https because that's exactly what your rewrite rule tells it do to.  Since there's only one site (certificate) configured on 443 (and not the one you're trying to hit).. tt's not trying to use the other cert, it's using the only cert it has since you haven't configured one for that specific server (it is the 'default' server for port 443)

Comment: @yoonix darn, I missed that `https` on the last line. I took all the rewrite stuff out and seems to work now.